# Get value after hitting enter Angular JS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to get input value  after hitting enter key ..

My xhtml looks like

```
                        <div class="medium-12 columns">
                            <input name="verificationCode" ng-enter="enteredVerificationCode()" ng-model="user.verificationCode" type="text" id="verificationCode" placeholder="Enter Verification Code Here"  />
                            <div ng-messages="formSubmitted &amp;&amp; signupForm.email.$error">
                                <div ng-message="required" class="error">Verification Code is required.</div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

As it is in my signupCtrl, my controller looks like:

```
Controllers.controller("signupCtrl", function($scope, $rootScope, restservice, $cookies) {
$scope.enteredVerificationCode=function(){
    console.log($scope.user.verificationCode);
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap it in a form tag.

```
<form ng-submit="enteredVerificationCode()">
    <div class="medium-12 columns">
        <input name="verificationCode" ng-model="user.verificationCode" type="text" id="verificationCode" placeholder="Enter Verification Code Here"  />
        <div ng-messages="formSubmitted &amp;&amp; signupForm.email.$error">
            <div ng-message="required" class="error">Verification Code is required.</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ng-Keypress](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngKeypress) to detect key strokes and look for the enter key (13) to trigger `enteredVerificationCode()` function.

```
<input ng-keypress=keypressed($event) ng-model="verificationCode">    

$scope.keypressed = function(event) {

   if (event.keyCode === 13)
       enteredVerificationCode()

}
```